# how to use cert in authentication with https server

Tags: python, ssl, https

the server provider provided to me a cert file in pro format without key in order to use it in the communication between my client app (in `python`) and the server.

The pem file (cert without key):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

MIIFSDCCBDCg........................................

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I tried to use the following solution but it returns errors

```
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, cert=('cert.pem'))
```

I got the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sauth-external.apple.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1.0/external/authEntityRequests (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(9, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4029)')))
```

Also I tried to use the following solution but it returns 401

```
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify='cert.pem')
```

I got 401 error code

Am I missing thing?
what is the solution to make the connection with the server and to authenticate with the server?

Comment: To authenticate yourself using a certificate you need the corresponding private key, that noone should give you as you should have created it locally. Other than that, at this stage your question seems offtopic as not related to programming, but just certificate handling and TLS auth in general. As for "what is the solution to make the connection with the server and to authenticate with the server?", the provider of the API you use should have documentation and support available to help you in that regard.

Comment: There are two things an X509 certificate with public key but not the private key is good for:  encrypting data that only the holder of the private key can decrypt, and verifying that the private key was used to sign some data.  Note that using just a certificate without the corresponding private key to prove identity as a client in a TLS connection is **not** one of those two things - as @PatrickMevzek commented, you **need** the private key for that in addition to the certificate.